# WMS satellite imagery: how to set up bbox

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, extents, imagery

I'm trying to retrieve satellite imagery in high resolution of a full country with a WMS API. I need them in HR since I want to perform a segmentation task on them. This is my code:

```
REQUEST_URL = "https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotorgb/wms/v1_0"

# BBOX = "52.358566, 4.854755, 52.407865, 5.018091"
BBOX = "50.57882393914561,3.170655050418618,53.63760758138347,7.4887368679516655"

PARAMS = {"SERVICE": "WMS",
        "VERSION": "1.3.0",
        "REQUEST": "GetMap",
        "LAYERS": "Actueel_orthoHR",
        "FORMAT": "image/jpeg",
        "CRS": "EPSG:4326",
        "BBOX": BBOX, # SouthLat, WestLong, NorthLat, EastLat  
        "WIDTH": "1000",
        "HEIGHT": "1000"}

response = req.get(REQUEST_URL, params=PARAMS)
print(response.status_code, response.content)
display_image(response.content)
```

Which gives me the image below. I'm not very familiar with WMS and I wonder how I would be able to extract all satellite images zoomed in properly allowing me to perform segmentation task, e.g. zoom level 12. I guess I need to set up the bounding box parameter with maximum width / height (to minimize the number of API requests) in a way that it slides over the whole country. How can I do this? [image]

This is an example of what one image could look like, preferably a bit larger. [image]

Comment: Zoom levels are not a thing with WMS, so `e.g. zoom level 12` is meaningless.

Comment: Max width/height allowed by the service is 2500 pixels

Comment: You may find it easier to use a CRS that uses m as a unit rather than degrees of epsg:4326 to work out your bounding boxes to give the desired resolution; for example you can use epsg:28992 like  https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotorgb/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=Actueel_orthoHR&STYLES=&WIDTH=2500&HEIGHT=2500&FORMAT=image/jpeg&CRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=101598.10026777269376907,411692.98036920191952959,101700.97822235836065374,411795.85832378757186234

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out! :)

Comment: Just two small remarks : 1) the data are aerial photos at 7.5 cm resolution, not satellite images. 2) The data provider have a (paid) service for bulk download at full resolution (WMS services are primarily designed for the visualisation of a dataset, so downloading from it is not straightforward) .